# problem with importing data from sql server to tabular model

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, ssas, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

hi i am using vs 2017 and sql 2017 versions 
i want to import data to tabular model from default server location 
what i tried: 
server: .
 
database:databaseName
mircrosoft login
username: myusername, pasword: mypw

server: serverName
 
database:
server login
username: serverName\user, pasword: 

and few other combinations and i cant get it working
error i get everytime
Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.
Thank you!

Comment: @Sasco, Can you provide a screenshot of how impersonation of the data source configured?

Answer (score 1):

What is the impersonation level set as in the connection?  This can be found be going to **Model** > **Existing Connections** > **Edit** > **Impersonation** in SSDT.  For a Tabular model use either `ImpersonateAccount` or `ImpersonateServiceAccount`, which correlates to the "Specific Windows user name and password" and Service Account options in SSDT, respectively.  From your question, it looks like the `ImpersonateAccount` option is what you are looking for.  If the model is already deployed, the current `Impersonation` setting can be viewed by connecting to the SSAS instance through SSMS.  After this, go to the model, then the **Connections** folder, right-click the connection you're working on a select Properties.  The **Impersonation Info** field located under **Security Settings** will display the current value of this property.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when just selected the "Use Windows Authentication" option for connecting to the server. This resolved once entered the required impersonation details as below:

Open SSAS solution: Choose "Data sources " and Edit

Then select "Windows Authentication" and enter database name

Click button "Impersonation" and enter username and password

[image]